Trigger terraform cloud plan & apply for .ftl/.css/.txt file changes that are not part of terraform working directory

In Terraform code base I have terraform cloud workspace set with Terraform Working Directory as "/terraform/application/non-prod/dev"

I do not have any other workspace & I do not want to setup another workspace for directory 'terraform/application/non-prod/global' with Terraform Working Directory as "/terraform/application/non-prod/global"

In terraform/application/non-prod/global directory I there is no .tf terraform files & has .ftl/.css.txt files in subdirectories .

my directory structure is like the below
- terraform
    - application
        - non-prod
            - dev
                - all the .tf files
            - global
                - some .ftl files 
                - resources
                    - some .ftl files



├── terraform
│   ├── application
│   │   ├── non-prod
│   │   │   ├── dev
│   │   │   │   ├── all the .tf files
│   │   │   ├── global
│   │   │   │   ├── some .ftl files
│   │   │   │   ├── resources
│   │   │   │   │   ├── some .ftl files

The issue is if I perform some changes in .ftl,.css & .txt files in the 'terraform/non-prod/application/global' directory it does not trigger the terraform cloud workspace for 'dev' with Terraform Working Directory as "/terraform/application/non-prod/dev"
and my 'terraform/application/non-prod/dev' workspace consumes .ftl/.css/.txt files updated/added in the global directory
How to trigger 'dev' workspace when every time when developers touch .ftl/.css/.txt files in 'terraform/non-prod/application/global/resources/theme-templates/abc.ftl'
I tried with the hash of all the files in the global directory but it does not work.
resource "null_resource" "global_file_change_trigger" {
  triggers = {
    global_files_hash = local.global_files_content_hash
  }
  # Define the base path for the global files
  global_files_path = "${path.module}/../global"

  # Collect all files in the global directory and subdirectories
  global_files = fileset(local.global_files_path, "**/*")

  # Generate a combined hash to represent the global files' state
  global_files_content_hash = md5(join("", [for file in local.global_files : filemd5("${local.global_files_path}/${file}")])) != "" ? md5(join("", [for file in local.global_files : filemd5("${local.global_files_path}/${file}")])) : timestamp()


Consider the following folder structure:
├── global
│   ├── bar.ftl
│   ├── foo.ftl
│   ├── new.txt
│   └── resources
│       └── 01.ftl
├── main.tf

Where main.tf contains:
output "global_files" {
  value = {
    for file in fileset(path.module, "global/**/*") : file => {
      md5 = filemd5(file)
    }
  }
}

Running terraform plan after changing some files, Terraform is able to detect the changes:
Changes to Outputs:
  ~ global_files = {
      ~ "global/bar.ftl"          = {
          ~ md5 = "9a9079887066e24ffad228bb1753cf9a" -> "0734bf7b4abc1ce2d43baa48b528bc67"
        }
      ~ "global/foo.ftl"          = {
          ~ md5 = "c5a8586ab96f542db2fd6856db08e3f8" -> "091d9445f7b657142a822e0c2384f606"
        }
        # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

Another alternative would be to use a null_resource for each file:
resource "null_resource" "global_files" {
  for_each = fileset(path.module, "global/**/*")

  triggers = {
    md5 = filemd5(each.value)
  }
}

Running terraform plan after changing 1 file:
null_resource.global_files["global/foo.ftl"]: Refreshing state... [id=8332604796426199442]
null_resource.global_files["global/resources/01.ftl"]: Refreshing state... [id=5548823420046972319]
null_resource.global_files["global/bar.ftl"]: Refreshing state... [id=1745825294617139687]
null_resource.global_files["global/new.txt"]: Refreshing state... [id=7198930859256488120]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.global_files["global/bar.ftl"] must be replaced
-/+ resource "null_resource" "global_files" {
      ~ id       = "1745825294617139687" -> (known after apply)
      ~ triggers = { # forces replacement
          ~ "md5"  = "0734bf7b4abc1ce2d43baa48b528bc67" -> "00ca7a06391c1fd91676be49aa2382e7"
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.

Please note I ran the above code on my local machine, not on Terraform Cloud.
The above code samples will work with folders outside the Terraform module as well, with minor changes - for example, using fileset(path.module, "../global/**/*").

Hey Rui, Thanks!
In your case it looks like the terraform plan is being executed from a directory where 'global' dir & mian.tf file both are under it & hence it is working for you & it will work on TF cloud also.

@SanjeshM my solution should work when using files outside the the Terraform module directory as well, as mentioned at the end of answer - just use a relative path in fileset function.

Thanks @Rui. Your example is valid & will work as your global dir & mai.tf file is already inside a TF working directory. My use case if different where files .ftl files are kept in a non working directory and terraform files kept in TF working directory are using these .ftl files. and I am not using any module here.

@SanjeshM I do understand your scenario. Yes I understand you have files OUTSIDE your Terraform module, as I already mentioned in my comments. My question is: have you tried to do something similar to what I proposed and see if it works, irrespective of where the files are? My solution should work with files OUTSIDE the Terraform module, for example using something like fileset(path.module, "../global/**/*").

Thanks! Yes I already used fileset function & tried with hash of the files. but it did not work for me. this note is also there in my details.

@SanjeshM if you add an output variable like in my example with a relative path in the fileset function are you able to see the files that are outside the Terraform module?
